Limit of a conditional probability
Consider two continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ taking values from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. Consider the following limit:
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \Pr(X\leq t+a| Y=t) 
$$
An assumption of a proof I am working on states that this limit is $\ell>0$ for each $a\in \mathbb{R}$. I do not understand why this is an assumption and why this limit is not trivially always equal to one for any $a$. Can you help me understand this better by answering the points below?
First, when $Y$ and $X$ are independent, then we have
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \Pr(X\leq t+a| Y=t) =\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \Pr(X\leq t+a)\approx \Pr(X\leq \infty)=1.
$$
Is this correct?
If the above is correct, I do not understand how the case where $X$ and $Y$ are correlated can be different. In particular, with some abuse of probability notions (forgive the fact that I am treating $Y$ as a discrete random variable):
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \Pr(X\leq t+a| Y=t) =\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\Pr(X\leq t+a, Y=t)}{\Pr(Y=t)}\approx\frac{\Pr(X\leq \infty, Y=\infty)}{\Pr(Y=\infty)}=\frac{\Pr(Y=\infty)}{\Pr(Y=\infty)}=1
$$
What is wrong in the above derivations? Probably I am messing up with the limit, but I can't see where.

I think you meant  $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \Pr(X\leq t+a| Y=\color{red}{t})$ in the first and second statements.

Yes, thanks a lot

The first statement where $X,Y$ are independent is correct.
The second statement is not correct, precisely, at the two symbols in red color:
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\Pr(X\leq t+a, Y=t)}{\Pr(Y=t)}\color{red}{\approx}\frac{\Pr(X\leq \infty, Y=\infty)}{\Pr(Y=\infty)}\color{red}{=}\frac{\Pr(Y=\infty)}{\Pr(Y=\infty)}
$$
In fact, this statement is not correct in general
$$\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{f(t)}{g(t)} = \frac{\lim_{t\to \infty}f(t)}{\lim_{t\to \infty}g(t)}$$
in particular, for the case where $\lim_{t\to \infty}f(t) = \lim_{t\to \infty}f(t) = 0$
Here is an example for illustration:

$Y$ is a discret variable that $\mathbb{P}(Y=t) = \frac{6}{\pi^2}\cdot \frac{1}{t^2}$ for all $t \in \mathbb{N}^+$
$X$ depends on $Y$ and follows the exponential distribution, the marginal density is $f_{X|Y=y}(x) = \lambda\cdot e^{-\lambda(x-y)}\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{x\ge y\}}$

The joint density function is
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)= \frac{6}{\pi^2}\cdot \frac{1}{t^2}\cdot \lambda\cdot e^{-\lambda(x-y)}\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{x\ge y\}}$$
For all $t\in  \mathbb{N}^+$, we have:
$$\begin{align}
&\mathbb{P}(X\le t+a|Y = t) = 1-e^{-\lambda a}\\
&\mathbb{P}(X\le t+a,Y = t) =  \frac{6}{\pi^2}\cdot \frac{1}{t^2}\cdot (1-e^{-\lambda a})\\
&\mathbb{P}(Y = t) =\frac{6}{\pi^2}\cdot \frac{1}{t^2}
\end{align}$$

Thanks for your clear answer (+1). Could you help with a related question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/656246/implications-of-lim-t-rightarrow-infty-prx-leq-ta-y-t-ell
