Implications of $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \Pr(X\leq t+a| Y=t)=\ell$
Consider two continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ taking values up to $+\infty$.
An assumption of a proof I am working on states that
$$
(*)\quad \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \Pr(X\leq t+a| Y=t)=\ell \quad \forall a\in \mathbb{R} 
$$
The proof in some step implicitly uses the fact that such assumption $(*)$ implies
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \Pr(X\leq t+r| Y=t+d)=\ell  
$$
where $d\in \mathbb{R}$.
I do not understand this step. In fact, $(*)$ is written when conditioning on $Y=t$ and not $Y=t+[\text{something}]$. Is this step wrong, or are the authors assuming something else, or is the implication simply correct?

I couldn't understand the basis but isn't $t\to \infty$ implying $t+d\to \infty $ too making the second one same as $(*) $?

The proof can be detailed as follows
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \Pr(X\leq t+r| Y=t+d)&= \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \Pr(X\leq \underbrace{t+d}_{t'} +(r-d)| Y=\underbrace{t+d}_{t'}) \\
&= \lim_{t'\rightarrow \infty} \Pr(X\leq t' +\underbrace{(r-d)}_{:=a}| Y=t') \tag{**}
\end{align}$$
As $(*)$ holds true for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, it holds true also for $a =r-d$ as well. From that, you deduce $(**)$ holds true.
